# For loop control with 1 variable start and another variable stop

Tags: loops, for-loop

```
int ix = 0;
int jx = 5;

    for (ix = 0; ix <= jx; ix++)
    {
       // foo
    }
```

In the above foo will execute 6 times if jx = 5

But what if jx = 0????

will foo execute just once? or not at all?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: 0 <= 0 is true; 1 <=0 is false

Comment: Print a message instead of `// foo`.

Comment: OP, you may find [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) useful.

Comment: @c.bear - Do you think they've been told that they can't run the code?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I was receiving an automated Windows update which failed, now I don't have a development environment, no way to compile this code to find out myself.   Thus the question.   I may have development environment back by Monday.........

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop, there are three sections 
for (initialize;precondition;post increment)

It's important to realize that the first time you go through a loop, it initializes **as well as** checks the precondition before even executing the following block of code.  Once it completes the block, the  is executed.

Then it checks the precondition to check whether it should go in to the loop again.